# How do you add dungeons to your minecraft world once you've already created it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I have a survival minecraft realm that with many of my friends on it. We've been playing for about a month and have build many cool builds and shops. The problem is that we wanted to set the dungeon count to 35 so we could build more spawners that could help us with surviving. The problem is that I forgot to set dungeon could. I only just realized this when I went into spectator mode underground and found nearly no dungeons. So, I'm wondering if there's a way to add dungeons without deleting our world and starting again. Please help and answer as soon as you can! Thanks!

Comment: An eye of ender can locate a dungeon for you.

Comment: That's actually called a stronghold

Answer (score 2):

*You can switch to Creative Mode in order to manually place some Dungeons.* **Or you might use MCEdit, which gives you a variety of world editing options.**

Comment: Thanks, i could try going on creative mode but unfortunately realms don't allow mods and plugins like mc edit

Comment: @Mobbuzzter Now i've got no experience in Realms, so I have no idea how it works. But, if you can just gain access to the servers world files, you could use McEdit or WorldEdit (which are stand-alone programs) to manually go in and edit everything. No plugin required.

Comment: @Mobbuzzter You can simply download the world to your computer, edit them, and reupload the world.